# ESP8266 Deep Sleep Wake Up

Tags: esp8266, sleep

I am testing esp8266's deep sleep mode. And i have some questions about that.

1- I want to wakeup esp via timer. I did it. I implemented GPIO16-RST connection and this version done.

2- I want to ake up esp with external button too. It means, I will use timer and button to wake up esp8266 same time.

Is it possible and how can i connect  button to RST pin that while GPIO16 has already connected to RST?

Answer (score 1):

The reset pin of the ESP8266 has internal pull-up. Connecting the pin to ground activates the reset of the ESP.

To create a reset button, wire a momentary push button between reset pin and ground. Pushing the button will connect reset to ground, causing a reset of the esp8266.

The io 16 pin is connected internally to RTC, which in deep sleep counts down the time and then sets the pin LOW. If io 16 is wired to reset pin, this resets the ESP8266 to end the deep sleep.

The only way to end the deep sleep of the esp8266 is a reset. There is no conflict between RTC io 16 and a reset button, both wired to reset pin. Both can activate the reset to end the deep sleep.